# Read array with key

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way in Java to read an array **without loop** for example get the first entry 
with index?

```
Object[] array = keySet.toArray();
```

something like

```
array.get(5);
```

I know that the get is not available with the current APi's  but maybe there is different
way to achieve it?

Comment: array[5] may solve your problem

Comment: dont quite understand your question, can you please be more precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the square bracket syntax

```
Object first = array[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try `array[5]` to get the value we can get values of array by index.**
As `array[5]` is itself a object and you can assign it to anyother object like

```
`Object obj = array[5];

obj.callMethods()`
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is `array[5]`.